# Why is my smoke only generated for the first frame?

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I have a smoke sim that is moving, and has forces affecting it, all seems fine and it moves how I want it to, but the flow object isn't continually generating smoke!
It only does it for the first frame and then that's it.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Need to set the type to inflow and not geometry

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Eric Xue, answer was as commented: Type needed to be inflow, and not geometry!